# How to convert CSV data into a dictionary using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a text file, job.txt, which is below

```
job,salary
Developer,29000
Developer,28000
Tester,27000
Tester,26000
```

My code is

```
with open(r'C:\Users\job.txt') as f:
    file_content = f.readlines()
data = {}
for i, line in enumerate(file_content):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    job, salary = line.split(",")
    job = job.strip()
    salary = int(salary.strip())
    if not job in data:
        data[job] = []
    data[job].append(salary)
print("data =", data)
```

My expected result is below

```
data = {'Developer': [29000, 28000], 'Tester': [27000, 26000]}
```

How can I convert my code to use `itertools.groupby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will generate the dictionary you wanted.

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    ["Developer",29000],
    ["Developer",28000],
    ["Tester",27000],
    ["Tester",26000]
]

def keyfunc(e):
    return e[0]

unique_keys = {}
data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)

for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    unique_keys[k] = [i[1] for i in g]


>>> print(unique_keys)
{'Developer': [29000, 28000], 'Tester': [27000, 26000]}
```

P.S: I would suggest using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read the file instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if pandas is an option:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_csv('job.txt').to_numpy().tolist() 
res = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in d: res[v].append(k)
d = dict(res)

d
# {'Developer': [29000, 28000], 'Tester': [27000, 26000]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only rely on [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if your data is already chunked into categories.

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("job.txt") as f:
    rows = [x.split(",") for x in f.readlines()[1:]]

data = {
    k.strip(): [int(y[1]) for y in v]
    for k, v in groupby(rows, key=lambda x: x[0])
}
```

With that in mind, I think a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is more appropriate here. Ordering is automatically handled and it's just less clever. Additionally, there's no need to slurp the file into memory or sort it (if unordered). Use `dict(data)` at the end if you don't like the `defaultdict` subclass.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open("job.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i:
            job, salary = [x.strip() for x in line.split(",")]
            data[job].append(int(salary))
```

As mentioned in the accepted answer, do prefer a [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) if your actual data is at all more complicated than your example. CSVs can be difficult to parse and there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.